# Smart Polygonal Annotation for Mask-RCNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision, annotations

I am working on a project where I need to annotate defects in around 450 images. I have already annotated 40 images using labelMe tool. The annotations are stored in form of JSON format.

First I converted the JSON files into COCO format and then I trained the Instance segmentation model using detectron2. Luckily I achieved good results.

Unfortunately the annotation task is taking very long. Moreover it is boring and frustrating. Is there any way to use my present model to automatically annotate images?

I want to generate the JSON files for remaining images using the my custom trained mask RCNN model. This will save tons of time for annotation.

Please help! Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly, yes. You can run your segmentation model, store the outputs in the same JSON format, and load them into the labeling tool to modify and verify. Note that the manual validation is ESSENTIAL, otherwise you'll simply reinforce the biases of the model by using it's predictions as ground truth.

The complete process would then be:

```
1. label or correct labels on data 
2. train model
3. predict more data labels
4. repeat as necessary
```

This technique helps "bootstrap" (not used here precisely in the statistical sense, so there is probably a more precise term) a trained model from a relatively lighter amount of data labeling, helping to deal with the fact that manually labeling data is labor intensive. I'm not sure if this would qualify as a weakly supervised learning method, since full ground-truth is eventually available and verified for each training example.